# unsynthesizable VHDL code

Tags: vhdl, fpga, xilinx, xilinx-ise

I am trying to make a DNA reader module using VHDL processes for Spartan-S6 series FPGA. The problem is that my code couldn't be synthesized. It works on simulation but in synthesizing it just stucks. I also googled about unsynthesizable VHDL processes but I think that I am doing it right and it must be synthesized well.
Here is my process code:

```
FSMOutputController:process(state,readDnaCmd)

variable clkCounter    :unsigned(7 downto 0) := "00000000";

begin

    case state is
        when zeroState =>
            if readDnaCmd = '1' then
                DNA_Read <= '1';
                SR_read   <= '0';
            else
                SR_read   <= '1';
            end if;
        when initState =>
            DNA_Read  <= '0';
            SR_read   <= '1';
            SR_clk    <= DNA_CLK_temp;
            DNA_Shift <= '1';

        when endReadState =>
            DNA_shift <= '0';
            SR_read   <= '0';
        when readState =>
            clkCounter := clkCounter + 1;
            --clkCounter2 <= clkCounter2 + X"01";
            SR_read   <= '0';
    end case;

end process FSMOutputController;
```

And here is a part of ISE's log when trying to synthesize :

```
=========================================================================
*                           HDL Synthesis                               *
=========================================================================

Synthesizing Unit <testDNALock>.
Related source file is "C:\Projects\Anti clone S6\code\test1\DNATest\testDNALock.vhd".
WARNING:Xst:647 - Input <CLK_98MHz> is never used. This port will be preserved and left unconnected if it belongs to a top-level block or it belongs to a sub-block and the hierarchy of this sub-block is preserved.
WARNING:Xst:2935 - Signal 'DNAVerify', unconnected in block 'testDNALock', is tied to its initial value (0).
Summary:
no macro.
Unit <testDNALock> synthesized.
```

and it stucks just in here and doesn't go for my DNALock file containing my process.There is an other thing: when I comment out assignment lines it will be synthesized correctly:

```
FSMOutputController:process(state,readDnaCmd)

variable clkCounter    :unsigned(7 downto 0) := "00000000";

begin

    case state is
        when zeroState =>
            if readDnaCmd = '1' then
                --DNA_Read <= '1';
                --SR_read   <= '0';
            else
                --SR_read   <= '1';
            end if;
        when initState =>
            --DNA_Read  <= '0';
            --SR_read   <= '1';
            --SR_clk    <= DNA_CLK_temp;
            --DNA_Shift <= '1';

        when endReadState =>
        --  DNA_shift <= '0';
        --  SR_read   <= '0';
        when readState =>
            clkCounter := clkCounter + 1;
            --clkCounter2 <= clkCounter2 + X"01";
        --  SR_read   <= '0';
    end case;

end process FSMOutputController;
```

Then the report will be:

```
=========================================================================
*                            Design Summary                             *
=========================================================================

Clock Information:
------------------
No clock signals found in this design

Asynchronous Control Signals Information:
----------------------------------------
No asynchronous control signals found in this design

Timing Summary:
---------------
Speed Grade: -3

   Minimum period: No path found
   Minimum input arrival time before clock: No path found
   Maximum output required time after clock: No path found
   Maximum combinational path delay: No path found

=========================================================================

Process "Synthesize - XST" completed successfully
```

You can check out my full [code](http://pastebin.com/bSjLM3nW) and [log](http://pastebin.com/tr0J7cTV) from pastebin.

Comment: Apparently you do not know what to do with the clock in a synchronous design. What you need most, I am afraid, is a VHDL book or course. As with all programming languages you cannot write decent VHDL code without a minimum knowledge about it. And SO cannot help here.

Comment: Renaud: I know it has some significant mistakes and I should learn more about it . About a VHDL book, I searched for it but I couldn't find a nice one. Can you Introduce a book please ?

Comment: Search for "clocked process" instead, read and learn... The synth report says you have a 98 MHz clock available ... use it.

Comment: The assignment `clkCounter := clkCounter + 1;` is done combinatorially  when state is readState.  A (gated or enabled) circuit  describing an array value with feedback and the potential for inversion of one or more of it's elements) is akin to an oscillator.  Note that synthesis generally ignores sensitivity lists, which can give 'reasonable' behavior based on event granularity during simulation. Combinatorial logic operates continuously not discretely in actual hardware without a clock and sequential logic.

Comment: anderwb has read the two files on pastebin you reference in your question and answered a question formed from the content of the testDNALock.vhd file found there and not in your question.  Your question as written does not form a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), depending on external content for the accepted answer.  Note that the Pastebin posts will expire.  How can this be of value to future readers?

Comment: @reza: Personally, I advice "Designer's guide to VHDL (Peter J. Ashenden), 2008, Morgan Kaufmann, 936 p.", or "Digital system design with VHDL (Mark Zwolinski), 2004, Prentice-Hall, 384 p." to my students. But there are many other resources, some on-line. Pick one and try understanding the basics. And, by the way, you also need a minimum understanding of digital hardware (flip-flops, latches, sequential design, combinatorial design).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure if it the only thing wrong. But as a minimum stuff like `DNA_CLK_Temp <= not DNA_CLK_Temp after DNA_CLK_period/2;` and `DNAReady <= '0' after 500 ns;` can't be synthesized. This means that most of you code is optimized away, as your clock never changes.

When you are simulating the code you should have a testbench module wrapping around the unit you are testing where clocks etc. are generated, instead of doing it inside your actual module.